# (lldb) error: anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

similar to
[Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003251/anonymous-closure-argument-not-contained-in-a-closure)
but lldb related

```
tableViews.forEach {
        $0.dataSource = self
        $0.delegate = self

        $0.estimatedRowHeight = 30
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ breakpoint is here
}
```

Trying to debug

(lldb) p $0.delegate

> error: :3:1: error: anonymous closure argument not contained in
>   a closure $0.delegate

(lldb) po $0.delegate

> error: :3:1: error: anonymous closure argument not contained in
>   a closure
>       $0.delegate

Visual debugging (positioning cursor on the $0) does work,
you get to expend the tree and go down to the variable you are interested in. But there is a slight problem there is a gazillion of them for uitableview so that visual debugging intention paves the road to the
comprehension hell

Given that visual part of debugging works there must be some way to get
there from the command line???? How could I get only the part I'm interesed in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "p" command actually compiles the text you type as though the expression had been in the text of the frame you are stopped in.  To do that it has to completely recreate that context. lldb gets a lot of this right, but it doesn't yet know how emulate the $ closure automatic variables in the context it uses to compile expressions.

But more generally, the job `print` tries to do is a much harder task that just viewing local variables, and not surprisingly lldb also has a more straightforward way to view simple local variables.  That facility is what Xcode uses to implement the locals view and the tooltips.  But it is also an lldb command-line command:

```
(lldb) frame var $0
```

The "frame var" command doesn't have a full language parser, for instance it can't evaluate expressions.  But it does allow you to specify elements of a struct, for instance:

```
(lldb) frame var $0.delegate
```

You might have more luck with the `frame var` command.

Comment: right, as you said frame var on $0 itself and it's props works, does not work on computed properties

Comment: which elder lldb gdb and objective c runtime somehow had many fewer problems doing

Comment: xcode 10.2 added "v" which works very fast. Dunno how reliable though, yet.